# PropertyNotFoundException on conditionally rendered subclasses in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, conditional-statements, el, uirepeat

I have a superclass `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    public abstract Type getType();
}
```

I have 2 subclasses of it:

```
public class JuridicalPerson extends Person {
    public Type getType() {
        return Type.JP;
    }
    public List<JuridicalBelong> getJuridicalBelongs() {
        return juridicalBelongs;
    }
}
```

```java
public class NaturalPerson extends Person {
    public Type getType() {
        return Type.NP;
    }
    public List<NaturalBelong> getNaturalBelongs() {
        return naturalBelongs;
    }
}
```

`JuridicalBelong` and `NaturalBelong` have different properties and can't be subclassed.

I have them in a `List<Person>` which I'd like to present in JSF/Facelets as follows:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.persons}" var="person">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{person.type eq 'JP'}">
        <ui:repeat value="#{person.juridicalBelongs}" var="juridicalBelong">
            ...
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{person.type eq 'NP'}">
        <ui:repeat value="#{person.naturalBelongs}" var="naturalBelong">
            ...
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

However, this causes the following exception:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.example.NaturalPerson' does not have the property 'juridicalBelongs'.

How is this possible? As per my `rendered` condition

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{person.type eq 'JP'}">
```

it should ignore `NaturalPerson`, right?

Answer (score 9):

This is caused by a bug in state management of Mojarra's `<ui:repeat>` which will expose when you use `EditableValueHolder` components (input fields) inside the `<ui:repeat>` as well. This is fixed as per [issue 3219](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3219). The fix is available in [Mojarra 2.2.7](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.7/) and for JSF 2.0/2.1 backported to [Mojarra 2.1.29](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.29/) as per [issue 3224](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/3224). So upgrading to at least that version (or just the latest available as per [Mojarra homepage](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.mojarra)) should do it.

Otherwise, your best bet is to replace `<ui:repeat>` by `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: You always have the right answer! Thanks for sharing your knowledge @BalusC !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't had the option to upgrade Mojarra's version and to avoid c:forEach (that causes many side-effects when used with ui optionally rendered components) I replaced ui:repeat with a p:dataList and it worked.
You'll have to do some CSS styling to hide the bullets but I think it's worth the price.
I hope it helps someone ;)