# Primefaces datatable not obeying conditional restiriction of rendered tag

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a code like this:

```
<p:outputPanel id="conditionalPanel">
    <p:panel rendered="#{object.category.string == 'foo'}">
        <ui:param name="foo" value="#{object}"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="fooAssignmentsuttonGrid">
            <h:outputLabel for="barToAdd" styleClass="desc" value="#{foobarzooUIData.label}"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="barToAdd" value="#{fooController.barToAdd}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{barsToAddAssignments}"
                               var="foobarzoo" itemValue="#{foobarzoo}" 
                               itemLabel="#{foobarzooUIData.buildLabelForObject(foobarzoo)}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton value="#{text['button.add']}" process="@this barToAdd" 
                             update="assignmentDetail" disabled="#{empty barsToAddAssignments}"
                    action="#{fooController.createNewAssignment(foo)}">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:outputPanel id="fooAssignmentsTable">
            <p:dataTable value="#{utils:toList(foo.fooAssignments)}" var="assignment">
                <!-- p:columns here etc..-->
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:outputPanel>

        <p:outputPanel id="assignmentDetail">
            <p:panel rendered="#{not empty fooController.selectedAssignment}" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                <h:panelGrid id="assignmentDetailForm" styleClass="formsTable" columns="2">
                   <!-- Some kick ass code here -->
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:panel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

The problem is, when I hit this page when

```
 object.category.string == 'foo'
```

is not satisfied, I am still getting:

```
/test.xhtml @264,147 value="#{utils:toList(foo.fooAssignments)}": The class 'com.foo.bar.too does not have the property 'fooAssignments'.
```

Yes, I know this class does not have this property, but this should not be evaluated at all, isn't it?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that you didn't post the full stack trace, as that usually represents the whole answer at its own which I could just translate into layman's terms.

Generally this will indeed happen during a [component tree visit](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#visitTree(javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext,%20javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback)) whereby the `rendered` attribute is [not obeyed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/visit/VisitHint.html#SKIP_UNRENDERED). The mention of the stack trace and the actual versions being used should reveal whether it's a "feature" or actually a bug in either the JSF impl being used, or in PrimeFaces. Generally I'd say that this would be a bug. This problem has before been observed with Mojarra's `<ui:repeat>` and has been fixed in that side. See also this related Q&A: [PropertyNotFoundException on conditionally rendered subclasses in ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594147/propertynotfoundexception-on-conditionally-rendered-subclasses-in-uirepeat).

If upgrading to latest JSF impl and PrimeFaces version doesn't help, then your best bet is to conditionally **build** the view instead of conditionally render the view. JSTL is very helpful in this. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

```
<c:if test="#{object.category.string == 'foo'}">
    <p:panel>
        ...
    </p:panel>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Primefaces itself has a bug to in its uidata usage in 'repeated' components (e.g. multiple datatables created via a ui:repeat or datatables in datatables.) e.g. https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6276 I've seen similar errors occurring then as stated above. The 'context' for resolving EL seems to be wrong in these cases