# Unrendered components are computed

Tags: jsf, el

I have a problem in my application.

I have a dialog, which should be available on all pages, so I included it in my basic template. To avoid unnecessary computations, the actual content of the dialog is rendered based on a condition. The condition seems to be correct, I can't see the content of my dialog in my html. But a lot of computations are done which orignate from this content, rendered conditions, loading of values and so on. This is of course a problem because I load a lot of data and do some operations before my dialog is called. Before that happens there are a lot of data and variables not present, which results in a lot of unnecessary operations and debug messages.

Maybe I understood something wrong in the concept or I am missing something. I useally work with h:panelGrid with a rendered condition around things I want to load at a specific point. The content of my dialog is included via ui:include to keep things clean.

What do I have to do to prevent the computation of those unrendered components?

I am using JSF 2.2 with Mojarra and Primefaces on a Tomcat Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28563356, http://stackoverflow.com/q/28802881, http://stackoverflow.com/q/28146767, etc .. All boil down to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984 Which one is for you most acceptable as duplicate?

Comment: I solved my problem with wrapping a <c:if> around my content. Thanks for the hints.